# Unique validation on entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following class

```
 public class PestanasPorEntidad
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Orden { get; set; }
        public string ClaseFontAwesome { get; set; }
        public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }

    }
```

As you can see this entity is related with Entidad.

what I want is to make a validation so that the Order column is unique, but not unique in the entire table, just for the same entity.

Is this possible with DataAnnotations? or should it be done server side on the controller actions?

Comment: You would have to custom code the validation. Annotations are only in the scope of the current object, so it can't know whether it is unique in a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough version of Entity Framework, you can use the `Index` attribtue. You also need to add in a property to your entity that specifies the column used for the `Entitad` navigation property.

```
public class PestanasPorEntidad
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    //Add this to specify a unique index for both Orden...
    [Index("IX_OrdenAndEntitad", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int Orden { get; set; }

    public string ClaseFontAwesome { get; set; }

    //...and also EntitadId
    [Index("IX_OrdenAndEntitad", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int EntitadId { get; set; }

    public virtual Entidad Entidad { get; set; }

}
```